# getting message content in on_raw_message_delete

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that will detect when a message is deleted, and send a message to the same channel with the message content.

I want to be able to do this even if the message is not in the bot's `cached_messages`, so I'm using `on_raw_message_delete(payload)`.

My problem is that when trying to get the message from the channel with `await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)`, I get the following error:
`discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message`

I assume this is because the message is already gone from the channel, but I don't know how else I would get the content or anything else from the message.

Here is my code (note that I have a `self` parameter, as this snippet is part of a cog)

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)

    channel.send(f'Message deleted with content: {message.content}')
```

I have also tried with `channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)`, but I get the same error

Comment: The message is lost. You need to cache it to retrieve its content. All the bot sees on `on_raw_message_delete` is https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message_delete#discord.RawMessageDeleteEvent however caching every message that might be deleted isn't a suitable method.

Comment: @TinNguyen
Is there a suitable method, then, or is it just infeasible?

Comment: If you know in advance what messages might be deleted you can cache them. But it is infeasible to just cache every message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`payload.cached_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawMessageDeleteEvent.cached_message) for this.

But the problem is, if the deleted message is sent when the bot is offline, then it returns `None` and I guess it's also the same if bot can't see a channel. If your bot will run uninterrupted, then there is no problem.

So you can simply do:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_message_delete(self, payload):
    message = payload.cached_message
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.send(f'Message deleted with content: {message.content}')
```